# How to retrieve which radio button within a LI is selected

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

```
<ul class="ulGroup" runat="server" id="ulGroup">
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="grouptype" id="rdGroup1" class="css-checkbox" value="Group 1" checked="checked" runat="server" />
        <label for="rdGroup1" class="css-label radGroup1">Group 1</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="grouptype" id="rdGroup2" class="css-checkbox" value="Group 2" runat="server" />
        <label for="rdGroup2" class="css-label radGroup1">Group 2</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="grouptype" id="rdGroup3" class="css-checkbox" value="Group 3" runat="server" />
        <label for="rdGroup3" class="css-label radGroup1">Group 3</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="grouptype" id="rdGroup4" class="css-checkbox" value="Group 4" runat="server" />
        <label for="rdGroup4" class="css-label radGroup1">Group 4</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How do I retrieve which `li` radio button is selected from code-behind.

When I run the code, I get the following error:

`Parser Error Message: Cannot create an object of type 'System.Boolean' from its string representation 'checked' for the 'Checked' property.`

```
using (SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection(gloString))
{
    using (SqlCommand qSave = new SqlCommand())
    {
        qSave.Connection = sc;
        qSave.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        qSave.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO [db1].[dbo].[tbl1] (FirstName, LastName, EmailAddress, UN, UP, DietGroup) VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName, @EmailAddress, @UN, @UP, @DietGroup)";
        qSave.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtFirst.Value);
        qSave.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtLast.Value);
        qSave.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAddress", txtEmail.Value);
        qSave.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UN", txtUser.Value);
        qSave.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UP", txtPass.Value);
        qSave.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DietGroup", rdGroup1.Checked); //Instead of rdGroup1.Checked, I would like to get which of the four radio is checked
    }
}
```

Comment: post also your code behind

Comment: @EnriqueZavaleta I added the SQL query code... Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this markup instead of yours

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="ulGroup" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Group 1" Value="Group 1" Selected="True"/>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Group 2" Value="Group 2" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Group 3" Value="Group 3" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Group 4" Value="Group 4" />
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

and in your code behind change this

```
qSave.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DietGroup", rdGroup1.Checked);
```

to this

```
qSave.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DietGroup", ulGroup.SelectedValue);
```

**EDIT**

If you want to maintain your markup, then just change your `checked="checked"` to `checked="true"`, also add the next using

```
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
```

then create a function like this

```
public string getSelectedRadioButton()
    {
        string radioSelected = string.Empty;
        foreach (Control control in ulGroup.Controls)
        {
            if (control.GetType().Name.Equals("HtmlInputRadioButton") && (control as HtmlInputRadioButton).Checked)
            {
                radioSelected = (control as HtmlInputRadioButton).Value; break;
            }
        }
        return radioSelected;
    }
```

now you can get the selected in this way

```
qSave.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DietGroup", getSelectedRadioButton());
```

Comment: I wanted to keep the format of the HTML that I posted for styling purposes. Is that not possible with the way I have it?

Comment: I add the alternative you want, the first option is faster, easier and more readable, but if you want to maintain the markup, then second will work

Comment: does exist or doesn't exist??? let me see how are your code now and try to put the foreach code by where you called rdGroup1.Checked, if rdGroup1.Checked was OK, then ulGroup.Controls should be

Comment: I had to delete the designer file and recreate it. Now I cannot select a choice. It seems like it is disabled. The first is auto selected, but when I click on the other input, it doesn't change.

Comment: It looks like another topic not related to the main question, if you have another different trouble than the first one, ask another question

Comment: Great Thank. I will open a new question and link it here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30130342/why-are-radio-button-disabled-if-using-the-code-runat-server my new question. thanks.