# Why are radio buttons disabled if using the code runat="server"

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

```
<ul class="ulGroup" runat="server" id="ulGroup">
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="grouptype" id="rdGroup1" class="css-checkbox" value="Group 1" />
        <label for="rdGroup1" class="css-label radGroup1">Group 1</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="grouptype" id="rdGroup2" class="css-checkbox" value="Group 2" />
        <label for="rdGroup2" class="css-label radGroup1">Group 2</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="grouptype" id="rdGroup3" class="css-checkbox" value="Group 3" />
        <label for="rdGroup3" class="css-label radGroup1">Group 3</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="grouptype" id="rdGroup4" class="css-checkbox" value="Group 4" />
        <label for="rdGroup4" class="css-label radGroup1">Group 4</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The above code works fine for me but when I add the `runat="server"` for each radio button it becomes disabled, meaning I can't select it.

I am trying to get the value of the radio button and use it to save to a SQL table:

```
public string getSelectedRadioButton()
{
    string radioSelected = string.Empty;
    foreach (Control control in ulGroup.Controls)
    {
        if (control.GetType().Name.Equals("HtmlInputRadioButton") && (control as HtmlInputRadioButton).Checked)
        {
            radioSelected = (control as HtmlInputRadioButton).Value; break;
        }
    }
    return radioSelected;
}
...
qSave.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DietGroup", getSelectedRadioButton());
```

Works (I am able to select it):

```
<li>
    <input type="radio" name="grouptype" id="rdGroup1" class="css-checkbox" value="Group 1" />
    <label for="rdGroup1" class="css-label radGroup1">Group 1</label>
</li>
```

Doesn't work (the option is disabled):

```
<li>
    <input type="radio" name="grouptype" id="rdGroup1" class="css-checkbox" value="Group 1" runat="server" />
    <label for="rdGroup1" class="css-label radGroup1">Group 1</label>
</li>
```

How can I modify the code, while keeping the style, to ensure the radio buttons are clickable.

**Here is an update**:

HTML output from ASP.net:

```
<ul id="CPB_ulGroup" class="ulGroup">
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="grouptype" id="rdGroup1" class="css-checkbox" value="Group 1">
        <label for="rdGroup1" class="css-label radGroup1">Group 1</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="grouptype" id="rdGroup2" class="css-checkbox" value="Group 2">
        <label for="rdGroup2" class="css-label radGroup1">Group 2</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input value="Group 3" name="ctl00$CPB$grouptype" type="radio" id="CPB_rdGroup3" class="css-checkbox">
        <label for="rdGroup3" class="css-label radGroup1">Group 3</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input value="Group 4" name="ctl00$CPB$grouptype" type="radio" id="CPB_rdGroup4" class="css-checkbox">
        <label for="rdGroup4" class="css-label radGroup1">Group 4</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

If, in Developer Console I change the two bottom radio buttons to that of the two top radio buttons, it works fine:

```
<ul id="CPB_ulGroup" class="ulGroup">
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="grouptype" id="rdGroup1" class="css-checkbox" value="Group 1">
        <label for="rdGroup1" class="css-label radGroup1">Group 1</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="grouptype" id="rdGroup2" class="css-checkbox" value="Group 2">
        <label for="rdGroup2" class="css-label radGroup1">Group 2</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input value="Group 3" name="grouptype" type="radio" id="rdGroup3" class="css-checkbox">
        <label for="rdGroup3" class="css-label radGroup1">Group 3</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input value="Group 4" name="grouptype" type="radio" id="rdGroup4" class="css-checkbox">
        <label for="rdGroup4" class="css-label radGroup1">Group 4</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Another update**:

```
<ul class="ulGroup" runat="server" id="ulGroup">
    <li>
        <asp:RadioButton ID="rdGroup1" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="css-checkbox" runat="server" Text="" GroupName="WhichGroup" AutoPostBack="false" />
        <%--<input type="radio" name="grouptype" id="rdGroup1" class="css-checkbox" value="Group 1" />--%>
        <label for="rdGroup1" class="css-label radGroup1">Group 1</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="grouptype" id="rdGroup2" class="css-checkbox" value="Group 2" />
        <label for="rdGroup2" class="css-label radGroup1">Group 2</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="grouptype" id="rdGroup3" class="css-checkbox" value="Group 3" runat="server" />
        <label for="rdGroup3" class="css-label radGroup1">Group 3</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="grouptype" id="rdGroup4" class="css-checkbox" value="Group 4" runat="server" />
        <label for="rdGroup4" class="css-label radGroup1">Group 4</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

HTML output:

```
...
<li>
    <span class="css-checkbox"><input id="rdGroup1" type="radio" name="ctl00$CPB$WhichGroup" value="rdGroup1"></span>
    <label for="rdGroup1" class="css-label radGroup1">Group 1</label>
</li>
...
```

This is what is shown:

[image]

Comment: ideally the radio button should not get disabled when you make them runat server. there is probably something else in the code that is disabling it. u can try setting the disabled property to false using javascript or jquery

Comment: Is there a reason you're avoiding the Web Forms asp:RadioButton control?

Comment: proib the comment dowm its maybe help us!

Comment: @post_erasmus For styling purposes... I will post what it looks like with style and without style.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge assuming that your CSS uses a selector like `input.css-checkbox`, you could use the asp:RadioButton control and change your selector to `.css-checkbox input` or `.css-checkbox [type='radio']`

Comment: @post_erasmus I tried that. You can see in the updated question what it outputs.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge Can you include your CSS for the radio buttons and label?  I'll attempt to show you what I mean.

Comment: @post_erasmus I will update the question shortly. Thank you.